# How to set common method for button Click event using setTag() and getTag in android?

Tags: java, android

In UI added 20 more buttons for these all buttons need to write common click event method using to tag of button. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement onClickListener into your class and in the onClick method you can put the actions for your buttons by using their IDs instead of tag:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button myButton;
Button myButtonTwo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
    myButtonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButtonTwo);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    myButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == myButton.getId()) {
        // do something
    } else if (view.getId() == myButtonTwo.getId()){
        // do something else
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

set `android:contentDescription="xxx"` to each button, and use `ViewGroup.findViewsWithText()` to find all views with the specified contentDescription.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 switch(v.getTag())
 {
   case 1:
   DoSomething();
   break;

   case 2:
   DoSomething2();
   break;

  default:
   break;
 }
```

and set the button click listener to this.

```
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Make sure you implement OnClickListener interface

Comment: Can you provide example code to impelment OnClickListener interface.please?

Comment: public class MyClass implements View.OnClickListener